# Template specialization for template

Tags: c++11, templates, template-specialization, eigen3

I have a function which uses the Eigen C++ library:

```
 template <class Type1>
 void myFunction ( const Eigen::MatrixBase<Type1>& matrix)
 {

 }
```

Now, I would like to specialize the template function "myFunction" for the type `std::complex<Type>`. Note that the type "`std::complex<Type>`" is again a template.
How to define such a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to note that `Eigen::MatrixBase<std::complex<...> >` is not a valid type, since `MatrixBase` is a CRTP-base class. E.g., `Matrix<double,2,2>` inherits (indirectly) from `MatrixBase<Matrix<double,2,2> >`, etc. However, every `MatrixBase` provides a `Scalar` type which you can check using SFINAE (i.e., using `std::enable_if`):

```
template <class Derived>
typename std::enable_if<Eigen::NumTraits<typename Derived::Scalar>::IsComplex, void>::type 
myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix) {
    std::cout << "Passed complex\n";
}

template <class Derived>
typename std::enable_if<!Eigen::NumTraits<typename Derived::Scalar>::IsComplex, void>::type 
myFunction(const Eigen::MatrixBase<Derived>& matrix) {
    std::cout << "Passed non-complex\n";
}
```

Godbolt-Demo: https://godbolt.org/z/Q9YlPz

Answer (score 0):

You can overload `myFunction` as:

```
template <class Type1>
void myFunction ( const Eigen::MatrixBase<std::complex<Type1>>& matrix)
{
}
```

Don't think of it as a specialilzation of the first function. It's just an overload.

The following program demonstrates the concept using `Foo`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
};

template <typename T>
void myFunction ( const Foo<T>& f)
{
   std::cout << "In myFunction(const Foo&)\n";
}

template <typename T>
void myFunction ( const Foo<std::complex<T>>& f)
{
   std::cout << "In myFunction(const Foo<std::complex>&)\n";
}

int main()
{
   myFunction(Foo<int>());
   myFunction(Foo<std::complex<int>>());
}
```

Output:

```
In myFunction(const Foo&)
In myFunction(const Foo<std::complex>&)
```

Comment: This won't work for `Eigen::MatrixBase`, since it is a CRTP-like base class and `Eigen::MatrixBase<std::complex<Type1>>` is not a valid type.